# Call vim command from shell script

Tags: shell, vim

I am using [vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki) as my local wiki and keep it in git in order to be able to sync it with various pcs. I am trying to automate the process of putting the generated HTML from vimwiki on my server so I can easily look stuff up.

My idea is to checkout the repository on a regular basis on the server and have shell script in place which calls vim and tells him to execute `VimwikiAll2HTML`, ending afterwards. I can then symlink the html folder somewhere or point nginx there or whatever.

I was able to figure out that I can directly execute a command when calling vim by using the `-c` parameter:

`vim -c "VimwikiAll2HTML" -n index.wiki`

This command automatically generates the correct HTML. However, I have to press a key and then quit vim (`:q`) in order to get back into the shell. It doesn't seem suited to be run inside a bash script run by `cron`? Can I change the command somehow in order to exit after the html generation finished? Or is there any other way I'm not aware of? I looked into the vimwiki plugin because I thought that it maybe uses an external library for HTML generation which I can call in my script but it seems that the plugin does everything by itself.

Comment: just a suggestion, what I am doing is, sync the generated HTMLs to github (github-page), since there are some private stuff in my vimwiki, I sync my vimwiki to dropbox. In this way I can access my wiki anywhere in browser, as long as github is up and running.

Comment: I thought about this. I am editing the wiki on pcs which don't have dropbox access for various reasons and I don't put my private wiki on github ;) But it's possible of course, so thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command should work:

```
$ vim -c VimwikiAll2HTML -c q index.wiki
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thank you very much. I played around with putting two commands in one `-c` parameter but didn't thought about using two `-c` parameters.